# Can passing an array of pointers to a function as an 'int' parameter convert the addresses to integers?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, type-conversion

Beginner c++ programmer, writing code to solve Sudoku puzzles. I'll keep the background info short to avoid confusion.

I have an array of pointers, `int *P[9]`, I have assigned each entry a specific address. I want to assign these addresses to another array of pointers, `int *B[81]`.

`P[0]` should correspond to `B[0]`, `P[1]` to `B[8]`, and so on.

When I pass these to a function:

```
void (int B[  ], int P[  ] ) {...}
```

it seems like the function is converting the address `P[ ]` is pointing to into an integer value. Before the function is called `P[0]` points to the address `0x7fff978d46b0`, if I check the value of `P[0]` inside the function it's a number like `48782346 .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void assign_box(int matrix[], int P[])
{
    cout << "P[0] in function: " << P[0] << "\n";
    matrix[0]=P[0];
}

int main()
{
    int table[9][9];
    //Initialise table entries to 0
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            table[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    //Assign addresses to vector P, for brevity P is of length one
    int *P[1];
    P[0]=&table[0][0];

    cout<< "P[0] before function: " << P[0] << "\n";

    int*B[81];
    assign_box(B[81], P[9]);
}
```

If it did this and worked I wouldn't care, but unfortunately when I assign `B[0] = P[0]`, it hits me with a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, which makes me wonder is the function trying to assign the pointer `B[0]` to the address 48782346.

Is it possible for the function to convert an address into an integer value?

Apologies if my question is unclear or verbose, first time asker. And thank you for edits.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am unclear on if the arrays are of `int` or `int*`, or some combination of the two.

Comment: Arrays are both int*, as in I initialised as: int*B[81]

Comment: Then why is your function taking `int` arrays? `void (int B[ ], int P[ ] )`

Comment: My compiler tells me the variable is 'declared void' if I have no type, if I use 'void(* B[ ], *P[ ] )' it tells me B and P were not declared in this scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dereference `int*[]` (or `int**`), you get an `int*`. If you dereference an `int*`, you get an `int`. This is exactly what you are doing, and why you end up with an `int` at the end.

```
//main
int *P[1]; //Array of pointers to int
int *B[81]; //Array of pointer to int
assign_box(B[81], P[9]); //Pass in two pointers to int

//assign_box
matrix[0]=P[0]; //assign int to int
```

You probably meant to call `assign_box` like `assign_box(B, P)`, and have the signature be `void assign_box(int *B[], int *P[]);`. This would then allow you to assign one pointer inside an array to another pointer inside an array.

There are multiple things that could be causing segmentation faults, but they all stem from invalid array indices. If an array is declared like `type identifier[size];`, it has valid indices from `0` to `size - 1`. So, `int *B[81];` means `B[81]` is invalid.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, this sorted out all my problems. Calling `B[81]` was the main issue, and in hindsight, a rather foolish mistake. Appreciate the quick feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in the wrong parameters. You're trying to pass in an array object B[81] which does NOT EXIST. You only have B[0] - B[80]. Also, B[80] isn't an int pointer. It's an int within an int array. P[9] is a pointer to an array of integers. So, you're trying to pass an integer in an array slot that does not exist into a parameter that does not take integers -- it takes integer arrays.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void assign_box(int matrix[], int P[])
{
    cout << "P[0] in function: " << P[0] << "\n";
    matrix[0]=P[0];
}

int main()
{
    int table[9][9];
    //Initialise table entries to 0
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            table[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    //Assign addresses to vector P, for brevity P is of length one
    int *P[1];
    P[0]=&table[0][0];

    cout<< "P[0] before function: " << P[0] << "\n";

    int*B[81];
    assign_box(B[81], P[9]); // WRONG

}
```